# Check For Existing Table Using variable

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how to incorporate a variable into a PHP statement to check if a table exists. For some reason the query does not accept the variable. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "stavacom_students";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id = "1";
echo $id;
$query101 = 'select 1 from "$id" LIMIT 1';
$val = mysqli_query($conn, $query101);
if($val !== FALSE){

echo "no";

} else { 
?>

what?

<?php
};
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to check database table exists or not?

Comment: Change `'select 1 from "$id" LIMIT 1';` to `"select 1 from $id LIMIT 1";` and it may work.

Comment: And in the place of variable `$id` you should use your table name.

Comment: The table name is the $id variable.

Comment: @JohnFinberg If your `$id` variable have the table name, it is fine. All you need to do is to enclose the query in double quotes, as I mentioned in previous comments.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS so it would look like this: $query101 = "select 1 from $id LIMIT 1";

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS It works as long as you add ` sandwiching the variable.  This is the final statement: $query101 = "select 1 from `$id` LIMIT 1";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement needed a tilde around the variable. Here is the final statement:
`` $query101 = "select 1 from `$id` LIMIT 1"; ``

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in two ways using mysql, the first one being a simple `SELECT FROM` type of query:

```
<?php
function mysql_table_exists(mysqli $conn, $table)
{
        $res = @$conn->query('SELECT 1 FROM `' . $conn->real_escape_string($table) . '`');

        if($res)
        {
                $res->free();

                return true;
        }

        return false;
}
?>
```

You can also do this by performing a check in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` using the following statement:

```
SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '<database name>' AND table_name = '<table name>' LIMIT 1;
```

Lastly, you can call `SHOW TABLES LIKE '<table name>';` and parse the results for a match, similar to the concept in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote("...Query...") Edit your query

```
$query101 = 'select 1 from "$id" LIMIT 1';
```

Into

```
$query101 = "select 1 from '".$id."' LIMIT 1";
```

OR

```
 $query101 = "select 1 from $id LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this, hope it work

```
$query101 = 'select 1 from "$id" LIMIT 1';
```

to this

```
$query101 = 'select 1 from "'.$id.'" LIMIT 1';
```